# Form processing problem with input type 'image'

Tags: php, html

For example i use this little code:

```
 <?php
      if (isset($_POST['Submit'])){
            if ((@$_POST['Submit'] == 'x'))
            {
           echo "OK";exit;

            }else{
           echo "NOT";

            }
      }
?>

    <html>
    <body>
    <form action="test.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="Submit" type="image" src="images/table/button.png" value="x" >
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

In Mozilla (3.5.5) works well, after submit OK was printed. I test it on IE8 and Opera 10, and not work. Nothing printed. The form not proccessed after hit, just reload the page.

Could you help me, how can i use image for submitting form, to work all browser? Thank you.

Comment: Your code got cut: try editing it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see your code because it got cut, but let me guess. You are testing like this:

```
if($_POST['Submit'])
```

while you should test like this:

```
if($_POST['Submit_x'])
```

because the image inputs will send Submit_x and Submit_y, and not Submit (but certains browser send this too, so you should contemplate various cases).

Comment: If the answer was helpful, and your problem was resolved, you should accept it.

Comment: Of course, i've just tested it many browser before accept. Thank you.